# Insufficient right to development workspace on contoso virtual machie

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I am using the virtual machine downloaded from Microsoft's PartnerSource.

I have been successfully developing on it for the past few months, but now I am getting the "Insufficient rights" message when I try to open the development workspace.

Is there something that needs to be renewed (it's being used for development of a plugin only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Demo license most likely expired on December 31, 2012.

Go to PartnerSource, where you downloaded the virtual machine application, and near the bottom of the page should be a download for Demo Virtual Machine Licenses. The new license says it expires on December 31, 2013.

Comment: Thanks, _should_ have been the first place I looked.